# Webpack isn't compressing javascript

Tags: webpack

Webpack seems to be compressing my css, but not any of my javascript. Any help is much appreciated, code from my `webpack.config.js` file below:

```
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './js/all.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme/assets'),
        filename: 'scripts.js.liquid',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader?-url', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                }),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css.liquid')],
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for compressing your javascript in debug mode?

Comment: Compressing it in production. It's outputting an uncompressed file when I run `webpack -p`

Answer (score 0):

Its not working for you because you have `mode: development` set up.

Please divide your file to 3 files:

1. webpack.dev.js
2. webpack.prod.js
3. webpack.common.js

**webpack.dev.js:**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
};
```

**webpack.prod.js:**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
};
```

**webpack.common.js:**

```
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/all.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'theme/assets'),
        filename: 'scripts.js.liquid',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader?-url', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                }),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css.liquid')],
}
```

and run your builds via this scripts in package.json:

```
scripts: {
   "build_dev": "webpack -p webpack.dev.js",
   "build_prod": "webpack -p webpack.prod.js"
}
```

then run from command line: `npm run build_prod`, does it minify the code?